# git branch -r vs git remote show origin

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

So I was looking for a way to see a list of all the branches that exist on the remote, and found the following 2 commands:

`1. git branch -r
    2. git remote show origin`

Whats the difference between the 2 commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `git branch` command looks at (or, invoked differently, modifies) your own repository's information.  For remote-tracking branches (`git branch -r`), this shows what's in your cached copy of what was on the remotes the last time you had your git contact those remotes and get updates.

The `git remote show name` command, by default, runs `git ls-remote`, which actually calls up the remote's server over the Internet-phone (or whatever other transport you use) and gets information from it *right now*.  This is what would be put into your cached copy, if you ran `git fetch`.  (Note that if you *do* run `git fetch` afterward, what you get by then could be totally different, since even a few milliseconds can be plenty of time to have massive changes occur.  It all depends on how active the remote is.)

You can tell `git remote show` to use only your cached copy, rather than calling up the remote on the Internet-phone.  In this case, the two commands use the same basic information (but present it very differently—`git remote show` is intended to help you show what `fetch` and `push` would do, while `git branch -r` simply lists what's in your cache).