# Difference between 'git branch -r' and 'git remote show origin'

Tags: git, git-remote

I've seen this answer ([git branch -r vs git remote show origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068739/git-branch-r-vs-git-remote-show-origin)) which notes that one queries locally whilst the other connects to the server. However, the displayed format for these queries is different.

Is there a difference in what they display or do they simply show the same information but formatted very differently?

Answer (score 4):

You can see exactly what's fetched from the remote server by comparing the output of `git remote show origin` with `git remote show -n origin`. The latter command will not connect to the remote server. As a result, it does not query which branch the server's HEAD is on, and uses locally cached information in a few places.

`git branch -r` shows information on which branches your local tracking branches push to. `git remote show origin` shows that, plus more information: which branch is checked out on the server, the URLs your remote uses, and how your git configuration is set up to treat a push.